# Why am I seeing different results for two expressions in Ruby, one uses '&&', other uses 'and' operator?

Tags: ruby, expression

> > print (-1 == -1) and (myobj.nil?)

true

> > print (-1 == -1) && (myobj.nil?)

false

Note, myobj.nil? returns false
so, should not this always be false.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In the future, please search the existing questions before asking your own. Chances are, it has already been asked, and, more importantly, answered. This way, we avoid duplication and keep all the answers neatly together in one place. Possible duplicates: http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2083112/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/1625946/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/1426826/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/1840488/, http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/1434842/, 
http://StackOverflow.Com/questions/2376369/.

Comment: @Jörg: Searching for `and` and `&&` in Stack Overflow doesn't work, and entering the question title in "Ask Question" didn't reveal any duplicates. Stack overflow regulars ought to know that related questions exist, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because they have different operator precedence.

The first evaluates as:

```
(print (-1 == -1)) and (myobj.nil?)
```

It prints true, because -1 == -1, then print returns nil and `nil and false` is nil.

The second is equivalent to:

```
print ((-1 == -1) && (myobj.nil?))
```

It prints (true && false), which is false, then print returns nil.

Comment: but why should that matter in this case, -1==-1 always evaluates to true, and myobj.nil? evaluates to false. so the net result should always be false.

Comment: oh ok, so if it was used in conditional expression like

if (-1 == -1) and (myobj.nil?)

both, would have same result?

Comment: @Shekhar: The return value of `print` is `nil`, at least in Ruby 1.8. Therefore, the first expression reduces like this: `(print (-1 == -1)) and myobj.nil?` → `(print true) and myobj.nil?` → `nil and myobj.nil?` (with the side-effect of printing **true**) → `nil`, while the second expression reduces like this: `print ((-1 == -1) && myobj.nil?)` → `print (true && myobj.nil?)` → `print myobj.nil?` → `print false` → `nil` (with the side-effect of printing **false**).

Comment: Jorg, thanks. this is really helpful, as I never realized print was being considered part of the expression.

Answer (score 3):

`&&` and `and` have different precedence. In particular, `and` has very low precedence, lower than almost anything else.

The return value of `print` is `nil`, at least in Ruby 1.8. Therefore, the first expression reduces like this:

```
(print (-1 == -1)) and myobj.nil?
(print    true)    and myobj.nil? # => with the side-effect of printing "true"
      nil          and myobj.nil?
      nil
```

While the second expression reduces like this:

```
print ((-1 == -1) && myobj.nil?)
print (   true    && myobj.nil?)
print                myobj.nil?
print                 false       # => with the side-effect of printing "false"
            nil
```